# androidx.compose.ui.window.MenuBar cannot be found

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to use the `androidx.compose.ui.window.MenuBar` from [Jetbrain Tutorial](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/tree/master/tutorials/Tray_Notifications_MenuBar_new) but the problem is that when I try to use it in my project it does not show up.

Here is the problem:

[image: Screenshot]

It only offers me to import from those 2 locations but when I use the import it does not complain or resolve the error.

build.gradle.kts

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.compose.compose
import org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.application.dsl.TargetFormat
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.10"
    id("org.jetbrains.compose") version "1.1.0"
}

group = "me.whate"
version = "1.0"

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
}

dependencies {
    implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>() {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11"
}

compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "MainKt"
        nativeDistributions {
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Deb)
            packageName = "Test"
            packageVersion = "1.0.0"
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to invalidate caches, etc but no success so far.

Anybody has any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to modify it like this:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
fun main() = application {
    Window(onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication) {
        var text by remember { mutableStateOf("Hello, World!") }
        DesktopMaterialTheme {
            MenuBar {
               // your menubar code here
            }
            Button(onClick = {
                text = "Hello, Desktop!"
            }) {
                Text(text)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and completely remove the App() function

Comment: That works but I don't understand why. How would I put the MenuBar code in a separate file?

Comment: Answered my own question, see below.

Answer (score 1):

The `MenuBar()` Composable is provided by `FrameWindowScope`, and if `this` is not a `FrameWindowScope`, you won't be able to access the function, regardless of whether it has been imported. In the tutorial, `MenuBar()` is called within a `Window` content block, something like this:

```
Window(onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication) {
    MenuBar { ... }
}
```

In this case, at the point where `MenuBar()` is called, `this` is an instance of `FrameWindowScope`. You can see this if you look at the last lines of the declaration of the `Window()` function, where the content parameter is defined:

```
@Composable
fun Window(
    onCloseRequest: () -> Unit,
    state: WindowState = rememberWindowState(),
    visible: Boolean = true,
    title: String = "Untitled",
    icon: Painter? = null,
    undecorated: Boolean = false,
    transparent: Boolean = false,
    resizable: Boolean = true,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    focusable: Boolean = true,
    alwaysOnTop: Boolean = false,
    onPreviewKeyEvent: (KeyEvent) -> Boolean = { false },
    onKeyEvent: (KeyEvent) -> Boolean = { false },
    content: @Composable FrameWindowScope.() -> Unit
) {
```

The easy answer to your question is to keep your call to `MenuBar()` inside the curly braces of your `Window` content block. This is a natural approach, as it keeps the code that's dependent on `FrameWindowScope` where a developer would expect to find it.

However, if you really want to call `MenuBar()` from within your `App()` Composable, you could actually pass the instance of `FrameWindowScope` into the function, and then call `MenuBar()` on that instance, like this:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
fun main() = application {
    Window(onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication) {
        App(this, this@application)
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun App(windowScope: FrameWindowScope, applicationScope: ApplicationScope) {
    windowScope.MenuBar {
            Menu("File", mnemonic = 'F') {
                val nextWindowState = rememberWindowState()
                Item(
                    "Exit",
                    onClick = { applicationScope.exitApplication() },
                    shortcut = KeyShortcut(
                        Key.X, ctrl = false
                    )
                )
            }
    }

    ...
}
```

While I don't think it's considered a best practice to pass scope like this, as it tends to make your Composables harder to reuse and to preview, I hope it helps illustrate some of the "magic" of how these scoped Composable function calls are made available in some places and not others. The key is understanding that within a Composable's content block, `this` is a very specific type of scope.

Answer (score 0):

Prefix MenuBar with FrameWindowScope, e.g. FrameWindowScope.MenuBar